# Paypal Gateway integration error in codeigniter - PayPal-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, sdk

On my localhost it works great, but on my server it show this error (Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/new_grantovi_com/application/libraries/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/common.php on line 119) and i don't know how to solve it, tried everything. If anyone can guide me what to look for, i would be grateful.

My Paypal Controller

```html
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php'); // require paypal files

use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\RefundRequest;
use PayPal\Api\Sale;

class paypal extends MY_Controller{
    public $_api_context;

    public function  __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // paypal credentials
        $this->config->load('paypal');

        $this->_api_context = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                $this->config->item('client_id'), $this->config->item('secret')
            )
        );
    }

    //stranica za placanje
    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['content']      = $this->parser->parse('paypal/payment_credit_form', array_merge($this->data), true);
        $this->parser->parse('main/container-content', $this->data);
    }


    public function create_payment_with_paypal()
    {

        // setup PayPal api context
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($this->config->item('settings'));


// ### Payer
// A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
// For direct credit card payments, set payment method
// to 'credit_card' and add an array of funding instruments.

        $payer['payment_method'] = 'paypal';

// ### Itemized information
// (Optional) Lets you specify item wise
// information
        $item1["name"] = $this->input->post('item_name');
        $item1["sku"] = $this->input->post('item_number');  // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
        $item1["description"] = $this->input->post('item_description');
        $item1["currency"] ="USD";
        $item1["quantity"] =1;
        $item1["price"] = $this->input->post('item_price');

        $itemList = new ItemList();
        $itemList->setItems(array($item1));

// ### Additional payment details
// Use this optional field to set additional
// payment information such as tax, shipping
// charges etc.
        $details['tax'] = $this->input->post('details_tax');
        $details['subtotal'] = $this->input->post('details_subtotal');

// ### Amount
// Lets you specify a payment amount.
// You can also specify additional details
// such as shipping, tax.
        $amount['currency'] = "USD";
        $amount['total'] = $details['tax'] + $details['subtotal'];
        $amount['details'] = $details;

// ### Transaction
// A transaction defines the contract of a
// payment - what is the payment for and who
// is fulfilling it.
        $transaction['description'] ='Payment description';
        $transaction['amount'] = $amount;
        $transaction['invoice_number'] = uniqid();
        $transaction['item_list'] = $itemList;

        // ### Redirect urls
// Set the urls that the buyer must be redirected to after
// payment approval/ cancellation.
        $baseUrl = base_url();
        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($baseUrl."paypal/getPaymentStatus")
            ->setCancelUrl($baseUrl."paypal/getPaymentStatus");

// ### Payment
// A Payment Resource; create one using
// the above types and intent set to sale 'sale'
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale")
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

         try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
            //print_r($payment);
            //exit;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
            ResultPrinter::printError("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", null, $ex);
            exit(1);
        }

        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isset($redirect_url)) {
            /** redirect to paypal **/
            redirect($redirect_url);
        }

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Unknown error occurred');
        redirect('paypal/index');

    }


    public function getPaymentStatus()
    {

        // paypal credentials

        /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
        $payment_id = $this->input->get("paymentId") ;
        $PayerID = $this->input->get("PayerID") ;
        $token = $this->input->get("token") ;
        /** clear the session payment ID **/

        if (empty($PayerID) || empty($token)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Payment failed');
            redirect('paypal/index');
        }

        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id,$this->_api_context);


        /** PaymentExecution object includes information necessary **/
        /** to execute a PayPal account payment. **/
        /** The payer_id is added to the request query parameters **/
        /** when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site **/
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId($this->input->get('PayerID'));

        /**Execute the payment **/
        $result = $payment->execute($execution,$this->_api_context);



        //  DEBUG RESULT, remove it later **/
        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
            $trans = $result->getTransactions();

            // item info
            $Subtotal = $trans[0]->getAmount()->getDetails()->getSubtotal();
            $Tax = $trans[0]->getAmount()->getDetails()->getTax();

            $payer = $result->getPayer();
            // payer info //
            $PaymentMethod =$payer->getPaymentMethod();
            $PayerStatus =$payer->getStatus();
            $PayerMail =$payer->getPayerInfo()->getEmail();

            $relatedResources = $trans[0]->getRelatedResources();
            $sale = $relatedResources[0]->getSale();
            // sale info //
            $saleId = $sale->getId();
            $CreateTime = $sale->getCreateTime();
            $UpdateTime = $sale->getUpdateTime();
            $State = $sale->getState();
            $Total = $sale->getAmount()->getTotal();
            /** it's all right **/
            /** Here Write your database logic like that insert record or value in database if you want **/
            $this->paypal->create($Total,$Subtotal,$Tax,$PaymentMethod,$PayerStatus,$PayerMail,$saleId,$CreateTime,$UpdateTime,$State);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Payment success');
            redirect('paypal/success');
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Payment failed');
        redirect('paypal/cancel');
    }
    function success(){
        $this->load->view("content/success");
    }
    function cancel(){
        $this->load->view("content/cancel");
    }

    function load_refund_form(){
        $this->load->view('content/Refund_payment_form');
    }

    function refund_payment(){
        $refund_amount = $this->input->post('refund_amount');
        $saleId = $this->input->post('sale_id');
        $paymentValue =  (string) round($refund_amount,2); ;

// ### Refund amount
// Includes both the refunded amount (to Payer)
// and refunded fee (to Payee). Use the $amt->details
// field to mention fees refund details.
        $amt = new Amount();
        $amt->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($paymentValue);

// ### Refund object
        $refundRequest = new RefundRequest();
        $refundRequest->setAmount($amt);

// ###Sale
// A sale transaction.
// Create a Sale object with the
// given sale transaction id.
        $sale = new Sale();
        $sale->setId($saleId);
        try {
            // Refund the sale
            // (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
            $refundedSale = $sale->refundSale($refundRequest, $this->_api_context);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
            ResultPrinter::printError("Refund Sale", "Sale", null, $refundRequest, $ex);
            exit(1);
        }

// NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        ResultPrinter::printResult("Refund Sale", "Sale", $refundedSale->getId(), $refundRequest, $refundedSale);

        return $refundedSale;
    }
}
```

[Common.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buyPU.png):

```html
<?php

/*
    Common functions used across samples
*/

/**
 * Helper Class for Printing Results
 *
 * Class ResultPrinter
 */
class ResultPrinter
{

    private static $printResultCounter = 0;

    /**
     * Prints HTML Output to web page.
     *
     * @param string     $title
     * @param string    $objectName
     * @param string    $objectId
     * @param mixed     $request
     * @param mixed     $response
     * @param string $errorMessage
     */
    public static function printOutput($title, $objectName, $objectId = null, $request = null, $response = null, $errorMessage = null)
    {
        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
            self::$printResultCounter++;
            printf("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
            printf("(%d) %s", self::$printResultCounter, strtoupper($title));
            printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
            if ($objectId) {
                printf("Object with ID: %s \n", $objectId);
            }
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("\tREQUEST:\n");
            self::printConsoleObject($request);
            printf("\n\n\tRESPONSE:\n");
            self::printConsoleObject($response, $errorMessage);
            printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        } else {
            if (self::$printResultCounter == 0) {
                include "header.html";
                echo '
                  <div class="row header"><div class="col-md-5 pull-left"><br /><a href="../index.php"><h1 class="home">&#10094;&#10094; Back to Samples</h1></a><br /></div> <br />
                  <div class="col-md-4 pull-right"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/developer/logo2_paypal_developer_2x.png" class="logo" width="300"/></div> </div>';
                echo '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">';
            }
            self::$printResultCounter++;
            echo '
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading '. ($errorMessage ? 'error' : '') .'" role="tab" id="heading-'.self::$printResultCounter.'">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#step-'. self::$printResultCounter .'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="step-'.self::$printResultCounter.'">
            '. self::$printResultCounter .'. '. $title . ($errorMessage ? ' (Failed)' : '') . '</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="step-'.self::$printResultCounter.'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-'. self::$printResultCounter . '">
                <div class="panel-body">
            ';

            if ($objectId) {
                echo "<div>" . ($objectName ? $objectName : "Object") . " with ID: $objectId </div>";
            }

            echo '<div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><div class="col-md-6"><h4>Request Object</h4>';
            self::printObject($request);
            echo '</div><div class="col-md-6"><h4 class="'. ($errorMessage ? 'error' : '') .'">Response Object</h4>';
            self::printObject($response, $errorMessage);
            echo '</div></div>';

            echo '<div class="hidden-lg"><ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="#step-'.self::$printResultCounter .'-request" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Request</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#step-'.self::$printResultCounter .'-response" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Response</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="step-'.self::$printResultCounter .'-request"><h4>Request Object</h4>';
            self::printObject($request) ;
            echo '</div><div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="step-'.self::$printResultCounter .'-response"><h4>Response Object</h4>';
            self::printObject($response, $errorMessage);
            echo '</div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        }
        flush();
    }

    /**
     * Prints success response HTML Output to web page.
     *
     * @param string     $title
     * @param string    $objectName
     * @param string    $objectId
     * @param mixed     $request
     * @param mixed     $response
     */
    public static function printResult($title, $objectName, $objectId = null, $request = null, $response = null)
    {
        self::printOutput($title, $objectName, $objectId, $request, $response, false);
    }

    /**
     * Prints Error
     *
     * @param      $title
     * @param      $objectName
     * @param null $objectId
     * @param null $request
     * @param \Exception $exception
     */
    public static function printError($title, $objectName, $objectId = null, $request = null, $exception = null)
    {
        $data = null;
        if ($exception instanceof \PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException) {
            $data = $exception->getData();
        }
        self::printOutput($title, $objectName, $objectId, $request, $exception->getMessage());
    }

    protected static function printConsoleObject($object, $error = null)
    {
        if ($error) {
            echo 'ERROR:'. $error;
        }
        if ($object) {
            if (is_a($object, 'PayPal\Common\PayPalModel')) {
                /** @var $object \PayPal\Common\PayPalModel */
                echo $object->toJSON(128);
            } elseif (is_string($object) && \PayPal\Validation\JsonValidator::validate($object, true)) {
                echo str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode(json_decode($object), 128));
            } elseif (is_string($object)) {
                echo $object;
            } else {
                print_r($object);
            }
        } else {
            echo "No Data";
        }
    }

    protected static function printObject($object, $error = null)
    {
        if ($error) {
            echo '<p class="error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> '.
             $error.
            '</p>';
        }
        if ($object) {
            if (is_a($object, 'PayPal\Common\PayPalModel')) {
                /** @var $object \PayPal\Common\PayPalModel */
                echo '<pre class="prettyprint '. ($error ? 'error' : '') .'">' . $object->toJSON(128) . "</pre>";
            } elseif (is_string($object) && \PayPal\Validation\JsonValidator::validate($object, true)) {
                echo '<pre class="prettyprint '. ($error ? 'error' : '') .'">'. str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode(json_decode($object), 128)) . "</pre>";
            } elseif (is_string($object)) {
                echo '<pre class="prettyprint '. ($error ? 'error' : '') .'">' . $object . '</pre>';
            } else {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($object);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<span>No Data</span>";
        }
    }
}

/**
 * ### getBaseUrl function
 * // utility function that returns base url for
 * // determining return/cancel urls
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getBaseUrl()
{
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
        $trace=debug_backtrace();
        $relativePath = substr(dirname($trace[0]['file']), strlen(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
        echo "Warning: This sample may require a server to handle return URL. Cannot execute in command line. Defaulting URL to http://localhost$relativePath \n";
        return "http://localhost" . $relativePath;
    }
    $protocol = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 || (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on')) {
        $protocol .= 's';
    }
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $request = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    return dirname($protocol . '://' . $host . $request);
}
```

And error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on a non-object in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/new_grantovi_com/application/libraries/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/common.php on line 119
```

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image. For more on this, 

please see why we 
[**Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2275490)

Comment: I don't know the source of this particular error, but I recommend you not use the deprecated v1/payments PayPal-PHP-SDK and instead switch to the current v2 Checkout-PHP-SDK.  There is a guide here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/